Preventing either hell or the devil from taking over the earth
This would have been a movie made in the 1980s or 1990s. It was color, in English, and took part in a big city. It had a theme about church and preventing either hell or the devil from taking over the earth. As always, there was a midnight deadline that everything was to happen by. 
I remember the ending only. I do not remember many details, but two main characters had been fleeing people (devil cultists and the church?) through the whole movie. They end up in one character's car at night as the time ticks down. Neither has fully believed that Character B is actually going be the key to unleashing the devil on earth for most of the movie, but sitting in the car, character B turns to character A and asks for them to to kill them (cannot remember if it is a guy or girl, but I think it is a guy). 
Character A is procrastinating on this. Character B is getting more upset. Just as the clock shows 11:59 Character B's eyes go funny (snakelike or black or something), and Character A shoots them. The movie ends with a pull-away shot of the passenger car window, bloody and everything staying the same. I think part of the idea of the movie was that you wondered a little bit if it was a real danger, or if this person had died for no reason. 

Sounds very familiar, especially the shooting at the end.  I think the idea is that Character B is the Antichrist, that's why they have to die.

The answer has been found. Lost Souls (2000). Thank you for all who looked. 

Could this be End of Days with Arnold Schwarzenegger?


Synopsis
  On December 28th, 1999, the citizens of New York City are getting ready for the turn of the millennium. However, the Devil decides to crash the party by coming to the city, inhabiting a man's body, and searching for his chosen bride, a 20-year-old woman named Christine York. If he bears her child between 11:00 PM and midnight on New Year's Eve, the world will end, and the only hope lies within an atheist ex-cop named Jericho Cane, who no longer believes in God because of the murder of his wife and daughter.


It was color, in English => Yes 
took part in a big city => New York, so yes.
It had a theme about church => The final showdown is in a church. And there are other church scenes as well.
preventing either hell or the devil from taking over the earth => That is the main plot. 
There was a midnight deadline that everything was to happen by => Again the plot; and it was specific to New Year's Eve of 1999-2000. 

The last scene I remember is the showdown in the church, not in a car like you said. But it has been over a decade since I watched the movie, so I may be forgetting a scene.

In End of Days the antagonist is clearly Satan himself rather than cultists, there is no doubt that the threat from him is real, as he performs several supernatural acts. The ending is also different from the one described Arnold Schwartzneggers lead character is possessed by Satan but he has enough free will left to kill himself before Midnight.

@Sarriesfan: OP himself was not sure about the cultists, only that the protagonists had been running from people. It's not impossible that Satan possesses multiple people during the movie (hence having to flee from multiple people), since he appears through possession of otherwise harmless civilians. I mentioned that it has been over a decade that I've seen the movie, and I was fuzzy on a few of the details. But the things I remembered from the movie match OP's description, hence my suggestion.

Thank you so much! I had a friend who thought it was End of Days, so I went out and bought that movie...and watched it...sadly, this is not the movie. Thank you for the idea though. . .
